# Perform filter through bridging table using Ef Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have three Models:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Role role { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a situation where I have to get User list based on some role, basically I have to filter user on the basis of roleId. How can I achieve that using ef core Linq queries.

I have tried the following query but it does not translates to SQL.

```
context.User.Include(it => it.UserRole)
    .ThenInclude(it => it.Role)
    .Where(it => it.UserRole.Contains(new Role { Id = 1 }))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried the following query but it does not translates to SQL

I would be surprised if this even compiles:

```
it.UserRole.Contains(new Role { Id = 1 })
```

`it.UserRole` is of type `ICollection<UserRole>`, so `Contains` would require a `UserRole` argument

To check for a `Role` with ID = 1, you could try using `Any` rather than `Contains`:

```
context.User.Include(it => it.UserRole)
    .ThenInclude(it => it.Role)
    .Where(it => it.UserRole.Any(ur => ur.Role.Id == 1))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked. I do have a question why contains() does not works and any() does?

Comment: `Contains` requires a `UserRole`, not a `Role`. You may be able to use `Contains` like this: `it.UserRole.Contains(context.UserRoles.Single(ur => ur.Role.Id == 1))`